# Maven/Spring: Automatic Test Run of Generated WAR

Tags: spring, testing, maven, war

Let's say we have a project that consists of some Eclipse-projects and Spring 3.1, the final result is a WAR-file. We use WTP for development. All the unit tests and integration tests are working (our Maven does this automatically). The project runs in WTP with a local configuration. In other words everything looks as if it is ready to roll.

Now we want to test run that WAR-file with different sets of configuration files for different platforms. The test should only start the context and see if that causes any issues (missing/misspelt property in a property file, too many beans for auto-wiring, ...). AFAIK it isn't necessary to have access to (or it accessible to) the outside world. Basically it should only start the context, close it and continue with the next configuration. If one context fails, the build should break.

How should we do this? Can we do this with Maven? Something external?

EDIT: Forgot to say: We will run our stuff with Tomcat 6.

Comment: There is the http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html with which you're able to "run" a WAR, it might get you some of the way. Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Guessing from the link I can't stop Jetty once it has finished loading. So I think we can't use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about integration test.
You should look at the failsafe plug for this:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html

> Using jetty and maven-failsafe-plugin You need to bind one of
>   jetty:run, jetty:run-exploded or jetty:run-war to the
>   pre-integration-test phase with deamon set to true, bind
>   failsafe:integration-test to the integration-test phase, bind
>   jetty:stop to the post-integration-test phase and finally bind
>   failsafe:verify to the verify phase. Here is an example:

Another possibility is a selenium test.  Selenium tests require the war to be deployed and running before the tests are run.  So there are plugins that do all this.
Then you would have a very simple selenium test case that just made a simple http request to the app to see if it was running.

You would use a different profile for each different configuration you wanted to test.

Comment: I would not use Selenium to just check the properties and make sure that you application serves pages. You can use any HTTP client library to do that, selenium is a good solution for functional testing or end to end testing of your use journey or flows within the application, and if the requirement is just to check the spring wiring and issues around property files then you can use the maven jetty plugin to serve some pages and use Jersey API or Apache HTTP Client to make some get requests and assert the response.

Comment: I agree, selenium is not best practice for the requirements, however, it could be good for a quick solution for someone who is not familiar with maven.

Comment: @Lithium I think I understood the concept of your idea and the plug-in, the part about running it multiple times looks interesting. However, we don't want to run the integration tests on it. They do take a while. We are confident that our current approach to integration tests works well enough so we can focus on just starting and stopping the contexts. BTW, IIRC having no tests causes the "tests" to fail.

Comment: After some more thinking and plenty of discussions we will keep this in mind. However, our first attempt will be a set of shell-scripts. -- So for those who are reading this I can't yet agree that this is working for me, but it sounds good enough to be the correct answer.